# Django MonthArchiveView returning wrong queryset on the 1st of the month (caching?)

Tags: python, django

I have a site that uses MonthArchiveView to create an event calendar.  The setup is very basic.

However, on the first of the month (for some number of hours), it returns the previous month's events.   I know that using datetime within a queryset filter can result in caching, but the get_queryset() for this CBV doesn't require any custom filter:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Lecture.objects.filter(status=True).order_by('lecture_date')
    return queryset
```

Is this a known problem with Django?   If I run things in the shell I get the right answer, which makes me suspect that the problem is that MonthArchiveView might not be entire thread-safe...

(I suppose I could try and override get_queryset to force the events returned, but it seems weird that the basic default behavior has this weird bug.)

Comment: Can you show the view that is causing the problem? It could be a timezone issue e.g. it is the first where you are, but the previous day for the server's time zone.

Comment: Please show the full view.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it got solved after I did the following:

I added .values() or .values_list() after the statement,

```
Lecture.objects.filter(status=True).order_by('lecture_date').values(´field´)
```

Give it a shot.

Comment: Here's the WEIRD thing about this --- if I try ANYTHING as a solution, as soon as I save the code, the server will restart, dumping the cache and the problem disappears for another month!  :-)

So, I'll definitely try it, but I won't know if it works until November!